# Debugging BinaryFormatter serialization

Tags: c#

I'm using a BinaryFormatter to serialize an object with different other objects in it. The serialization results in an endless loop with one of these objects and after hours looking through them I can't find where this loop causes. Is there a possibility to debug the serialization process step by step in VisualStudio or is there another tool to do this?

Comment: Do you get `StackOverflowException`? If not then it is not serializer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is add `[NonSerialized]` attributes to the class members until serialization succeeds. It's not exactly debugging, but may quickly find the member causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `OnSerializing` or on `OnSerialized` attributes that allow you to hook into serialization process. (See [ref1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ref2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It moreless means that with following definition

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo{

   [OnSerializing]
   public void DebugHook(StreamingContext context){
     //here goes magic stuff...
   }
}
```

your breakpoint inside the method will be caught by visual studio.